# R: transform jQuery widget as plain html or png

Tags: jquery, html, r, widget

I have created a widget using `formattable`

```
library(formattable)
products <- data.frame(id = 1:5, 
                       price = c(10, 15, 12, 8, 9),
                       rating = c(5, 4, 4, 3, 4),
                       market_share = percent(c(0.1, 0.12, 0.05, 0.03, 0.14)),
                       revenue = accounting(c(55000, 36400, 12000, -25000, 98100)),
                       profit = accounting(c(25300, 11500, -8200, -46000, 65000)))
sign_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                            style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x > 0, "green", 
                                                             ifelse(x < 0, "red", "black"))))
f = formattable(products, list(profit = sign_formatter))
f
```

Which displays nicely. However I need to put the result as body of an email hence cannot use external jQuery libraries. is there a way to transform it into plain html, without losing the coloring?

Alternatively, is there a way to programmatically create a png from the formattable?

Thank you

EDIT: second example a bit more advanced and is 'simplified' when applying `as.htmlwidget`

```
f = formattable(products, list(
  price = color_tile("transparent", "lightpink"),
  rating = color_bar("lightgreen"),
  market_share = color_bar("lightblue"),
  revenue = sign_formatter,
  profit = sign_formatter))
f
```

Comment: try the `webshot` package.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Error in UseMethod("appshot") : 
  no applicable method for 'appshot' applied to an object of class "c('formattable', 'data.frame')"

Comment: I have no idea what you did to invoke the function. Random error message w/o real context are nigh un-debuggable.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I used example above then `webshot::appshot(f)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# You need these
library(webshot)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(magick)

# it's not a widget by default so make it one
f_w <- as.htmlwidget(f)

# save it out to a file
saveWidget(f_w, "out.html")

# it's not a shiny app
webshot("out.html", file = "out.png")

# you have what you want but there's alot of whitespace
image_read("out.png")
```

[image]

```
# so we can deal with that
img <- image_read("out.png")
img <- image_trim(img)
image_write(img, "out2.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how plain you want the HTML to be. You could do the following:

```
f <- formattable(products, list(profit = sign_formatter))
h <- as.htmlwidget(f)
cat(h$x$html)
```

This outputs the HTML of the table to the console - you can assign it to variables as you wish, of course.

Notably, this preserves your `formatter`-assigned layout (green/red text) but strips the table of R's standard table design. For its standard layout, R uses the Bootstrap library which you can also find as a CSS file [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp).